# Firefox convertImgToDataURLviaCanvas is not working on Firefox but working in chrome and IE

Tags: image, firefox, canvas

My following function is not working in firefox but works in chrome

```
function convertImgToDataURLviaCanvas(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

I have to pass the base64 encoded to a webservice, the encoded string which I am getting in firefox is failing at webservice end, but the one I am getting in chrome and IE is working. Following is the code which gets called on Imageupload

```
  $("#avatar1").on('change',function(event){
  var selectedFile = this.files[0];
  var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
 // $('.profile-image').append('<img src="'+tmppath+'" />');
  var convertFunction = convertImgToDataURLviaCanvas;
    convertFunction(tmppath, function(base64Img){
            console.log(base64Img);
        var imagebase64Obj = new Object();
        imagebase64Obj.data = base64Img;


        $.ajax({
                url : "/bin/mercer/saml/myProfileController?q=updateavatar",
                type : "POST",
                data : imagebase64Obj,
                success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // data - response from server
                    window.location.reload();
                alert("success");
            },
                  error : function(jqXHR, textStatus,
                  errorThrown) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });



});
```

Please help me get what is going wrong, or some other variant function which works in firefox

Comment: when you do append a new Image with the dataURI has `src` into the DOM, does it show the image ?

Comment: Yes it shows the image

Comment: Then the issue is probably in the `$.ajax` call. Can you check both Chrome and FF Network panel of your developer tools to see what differs in their requests ?

Comment: Hi Kaiido , Sorry for my wrong answer, actually it doesnt show the image in firefox

Comment: ah then can you try to remove the `crossOrigin ='Anonymous'` line?

Comment: @PallaviSingh check through Inspect Element your html page and then If there are any errors showing on Console or not, then you will get to know actual problem.